# How to query ManyToManyField linked with a Foreign Key and that Foreign Key is linked with another Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django

I have created a TimeTable model that is linked to the Period Model via ManyToManyField and the Period Model is linked to the PeriodData via a Foreign Key. The models are working fine but I have very little idea of how to query the data. Here is the TimeTableModel -

> TimeTable Model

```
class TimeTable(models.Model):                                                          
    class_id = models.OneToOneField(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                  
    monday = models.ManyToManyField('Period', related_name='monday', blank=True)        
    tuesday = models.ManyToManyField('Period', related_name='tuesday', blank=True)      
    wednesday = models.ManyToManyField('Period', related_name='wednesday', blank=True)  
    thursday = models.ManyToManyField('Period', related_name='thursday', blank=True)    
    friday = models.ManyToManyField('Period', related_name='friday', blank=True)        
    saturday = models.ManyToManyField('Period', related_name='saturday', blank=True)
```

> Period Model

```
class Period(models.Model):                                                                                             
    period_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)                                                            
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                                     
    period1 = models.ForeignKey('PeriodData', related_name='period1', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    period2 = models.ForeignKey('PeriodData', related_name='period2', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    period3 = models.ForeignKey('PeriodData', related_name='period3', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    period4 = models.ForeignKey('PeriodData', related_name='period4', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    period5 = models.ForeignKey('PeriodData', related_name='period5', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> PeriodData Model

```
class PeriodData(models.Model):
    period_data_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_id = models.ForeignKey(Subject, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

Let's say that there is a `class1` and on `monday` it has `maths` as its `period1` and `bio` as its `period2` and so on. And there's another `class2` and on `monday` it has `physics` as its `period1` and `chemistry` as its `period2` and so on.

So how am I should I query the timetable for `class1` and see which periods are on  `monday` and etc.?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try like this:

```
monday_periods = TimeTable.objects.get(class_id__class_id='class1').monday.all() # assuming class_id is a field in Class model
# get values query set:
monday_periods.values('period1__subject_id', 'period2__subject_id__name','period3__subject_id__name') # and so on
# I am assuming Subject model has field name

# Or directly get the PeriodData object
for period in monday_periods.prefetch_related('period1', 'period2'):  # and so on
   print(period.period1.subject_id.name)
   print(period.period2.subject_id.name)
```

But, I think your model structure contains unnecessary relationships. For example, you do not need many to many relationship as you already have a Foreign Key relation from `Period` to `Class`. Based on that, you can make the query.

I can suggest a simplified version of this model sturcture:

```
WEEK_DAYS = [('mon', 'Monday'), ('tue', 'Tuesday')] # so on

class Period(models.Model):  
    period_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, primary_key=True)                                                                                            
    class = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='timetable')                                                     
    day = models.CharField(choices= WEEK_DAYS, max_length=30)
    
class PeriodData(models.Model):
    period_data_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

Then simply query by:

```
period_data = Class.objects.get(class_id='class1').timetable.get(day='mon').perioddata_set.all()
```